# How to put the page number into the top right corner + issue?

Tags: page-numbering

I copied this code from a German online forum. 
It is supposed to put the pagenumber to the top right.

A problem I have been encountering: 
The page numbers mostly alternate from bottom (center) to top right, when applying this code. When this code is not used, the pagenumbers are centered.
I can't figure out why this alternation happens.

I hope it is okay to ask this here. (Please tell me if you need more information)

```
\documentclass[
    egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles,
    headings=optiontoheadandtoc,
    chapterprefix=true,
    toc=chapterentrywithdots
    ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %pagenumber top right
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{0cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
   \fancyhf{}%
   \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
Titlepage
\end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{roman}\setcounter{page}{2} %pagenumber
\chapter*{Abstract}

\addchap{Introduction}%\setcounter{page}{1} 
\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{1}
```

Comment: The use of `fancyhdr` together with KOMS-script classses such as `scrreprt` is, as the corresponsing warning message that you should get from the posted code tells you, is not recommended. Take a look as the `scrlayer-scrpage` package instead.

Comment: Could you please add some clarifications regarding the desired output: Since the first page of a chapter and the following pages of the same chapter are treated differently regarding headers and footers, do you also want the page number in the right header for first pages of a chapter or only for the following pages?

Comment: Yes, I would like all the pagenumbers top/right throughout the whole document.

Comment: Off topic: I would suggest to replace `\chapter*{Abstract}` by `\addchap*{Abstract}`.

Comment: thanks @esdd but unfortunately I can't do that as the chapters + numbers on top of the page would disappear (cf. other questions I asked).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the before mentioned `scrlayer-scrpage` package and the `\ohead*` command:

```
\documentclass[
    egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles,
    headings=optiontoheadandtoc,
    chapterprefix=true,
    toc=chapterentrywithdots
    ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{titlepage}
Titlepage
\end{titlepage}

\chapter*{Abstract}

\addchap{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\newpage
some contents here
\end{document}
```

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: Command \chead already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                                                                        
l.101 ...ef\f@nch@och{#2}\f@nch@def\f@nch@ech{#1}}

Comment: This error comes up when I use your code - unfortunately I don't know what it means

Comment: Remove the `fancyhdr` package and the related commands from your preamble. `fancyhdr` and `scrlayer-scrpage` can not be used together in the same document.

Comment: Thank it worked!